# Typo3 6.1.7: How to load Javascript-file in own extension in the left backend-iframe?

Tags: javascript, backend, typo3-6.1.x

in my own extension I added some JS:

```
$GLOBALS['TBE_MODULES']['_configuration'][$_EXTKEY] = array (
    'jsFiles' => array (
        'EXT:' . $_EXTKEY . '/Resources/Public/Javascript/be-script.js',
    ),
);
```

(ext_tables.php)

Problem is that this JS-file is added in the top frame of the backend but I need it in the editing mode of an element of my extension. How do I define in which iframe the JS is loaded?

Answer (score 1):

You can load your javascript and stylesheets with fluid `f:be.containter`

example for a css file :

```
<f:be.container addCssFile="{f:uri.resource(path:'css/style.css')}">
something
</f:be.container>
```

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/Be/Container.html

Comment: This still applies to TYPO3 v6.2 and v7.6, too.